# on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, mqtt

[(ERROR MODULE) python mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983408/error-module-python-mqtt-listen-sensor-data-py)
Previously I had a problem with localhost but now im getting another error. I'm trying to store my MQTT data in SQLITE database on raspberry. What am I doing wrong to get the error below?

CODE:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from store_Sensor_Data_to_DB import sensor_Data_Handler

# MQTT Settings 
MQTT_Broker = "localhost"
MQTT_Port = 1883
Keep_Alive_Interval = 45
MQTT_Topic = "kuca/primanje/kanta01/r"

#Subscribe to all Sensors at Base Topic
def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
       self.subscribe(MQTT_Topic,0)

#Save Data into DB Table
def on_message(mosq, obj, msg):
        self.subscribe(MQTT_Topic, 0)
    # This is the Master Call for saving MQTT Data into DB
    # For details of "sensor_Data_Handler" function please refer "sensor_data_to_db.py"
    print "MQTT Data Received..."
    print "MQTT Topic: " + msg.topic  
    print "Data: " + msg.payload
    sensor_Data_Handler(msg.topic, msg.payload)

def on_subscribe(mosq, obj, mid, granted_qos):

    pass

mqttc = mqtt.Client()
# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe

# Connect
mqttc.connect(MQTT_Broker, int(MQTT_Port), int(Keep_Alive_Interval))

# Continue the network loop
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

---

ERROR:

```
pi@Pi:~/Desktop/SQLITE $ python mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mqtt_Listen_Sensor_Data.py", line 46, in <module>
    mqttc.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1481, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1003, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1284, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1849, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2311, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_connack()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2372, in _handle_connack
    self.on_connect(self, self._userdata, flags_dict, result)
TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

I am really sorry for having troubled you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem resides here: you define a **function**, and address the `self` without actually passing it:

```
#Subscribe to all Sensors at Base Topic
def on_connect(mosq, obj, rc):
       self.subscribe(MQTT_Topic,0)
```

Then you create an object, and *assign your function as an attribute of that object*:

```
mqttc = mqtt.Client()
# Assign event callbacks
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
```

Your `on_connect` function isn't an *instance method*.

> When you call an instance *method*, the self variable is passed as first argument.

So when you call `mgttc.on_connect(x, y, z)` what actually executed is `mgttc.on_connect(self, x, y, z)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind. The problem with on_connect() is fixed but now there is still error with mqttc.loop_forever()

Answer (score 0):

Your on_connect() callback must have this signature (from [paho python doc](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/#callbacks)) :

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
```

If you want to use it in another class you can use this signature :

```
def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
```

Furthermore, variable self is undefined in the on_connect() and on_message() callbacks, for example :

```
self.subscribe(MQTT_Topic,0)
```

must be

```
mqttc.subscribte(MQTT_Topic, 0)
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind. Your code fixed the problem with on_connect() but there is still error with mqttc.loop_forever()

Comment: Same as before just without TypeError: on_connect() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given).
Forever loop is problem now